# How to install bluez-hid2hci?

Tags: debian, software-installation, bluetooth, bluez

I've been trying to connect my Debian computer to my Bluetooth speakers, using `bluetoothctl`.

I managed to pair the devices, but can't seem to connect them.

```
[bluetooth]# devices
Device X:X:X:X:X:X BT_SPEAKERS
[bluetooth]# connect X:X:X:X:X:X
Attempting to connect to X:X:X:X:X:X
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]#
```

I found online various posts that tend to agree that installing `bluez-hid2hci` resolves the problem.

However, I can't install this package, it doesn't seem to exist:

```
apt-get install bluez-hid2hci
E: Unable to locate package bluez-hid2hci
```

How can I install this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid `bluez-hid2hci` won't help you.

Some Bluetooth keyboards, mice and/or systems designed to be used wirelessly are using a special Bluetooth transceiver that will hide the "Bluetooth-ness" of a mouse/keyboard connection, so the transceiver will appear to the computer as a simple USB mouse and/or keyboard. This allows e.g. the use of a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard for the task of installing an operating system, during which the regular Bluetooth drivers of the OS are not yet active.

The technical term for such a transceiver is a *HID proxying bluetooth HCI*.

The purpose of `bluez-hid2hci` is to get such Bluetooth transceivers out of their "hide-the-Bluetooth-connection" mode, to allow them to be used as regular general-purpose Bluetooth transceivers (HCIs) instead of just with a keyboard and/or mouse.

But since you have already managed to pair the Bluetooth speakers, that means your Bluetooth transceiver must already be in the normal HCI mode. So `bluez-hid2hci` would have nothing to do.

Anyway, the separate `bluez-hid2hci` package from year 2009 has since then been integrated to the main `bluez` package, and so the tool should be already installed on your system and available `/lib/udev/hid2hci`. There should also be an udev rule file `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules` to invoke it automatically whenever needed.

In your question, you're trying to connect to the Bluetooth speakers as `root`. Debian 10's default audio setup now uses Pulseaudio, which will normally handle the Bluetooth audio connections. The catch is that the Pulseaudio daemon is normally run as a *per-user service*, so it will be running as the user account that's currently logged-in locally. If you make the Bluetooth connection as root while the Pulseaudio daemon is running as a non-root user, the daemon might not be able to use the connection at all. Alternatively, the reason why you cannot connect to the speakers as root might be that the Pulseaudio daemon may have already established another connection as a different user.

A lot of internet advice about Bluetooth on Linux is based on the old BlueZ 4.x series. When BlueZ 5.x was initially released (in 2012 or so) and adopted by the distributions, much of that old advice became obsolete. When searching the Internet for Linux Bluetooth advice, pay attention to when that advice was written.

Answer (score 0):

hi here  is what  helped me with

"Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed"
while following  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_keyboard

1. Remove Bluetooth device in error from list of devices detected by the PC
2. Re-star   the linux box
3. Pair again and Reconnect
   tip was from this French man mr.Ronan :
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5pH0JrwynQ

my issue was :  I had correct  pairing and trusted    bluetooth  keyboard device but for some reason i got this  annoying  error "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed"
(Maybe because i did not use keyboard  for long time or laptop had issue connecting to it after  standby) .  I tried all kind of tips from forums and only this trick from mr.Ronan helped me... and might help you.

I found your question   cause many (old) forum posts  advised to  install bluez-hid2hci (as alpereira7  mentioned) .  Thanx to  telcoM's  great explanation we now know this is not the issue.

Behind Xubuntu 18.04 , installed latest from repository bluez* , bluetoothctl: 5.48